# Dynamically changing the command list submitted to Executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to change the list of commands submitted to the executor service at runtime. Has anyone tried doing that? Can multiple commands be submitted via a single executor service instance? Can the list of commands submitted be changed at runtime  (I might add or remove commands previously submitted to the executor, at runtime)

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You pass `Runnable` objects to the Executor Service, so nothing prevents you from creating a custom one at runtime...

Comment: How about queuing the tasks within a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), and submitting the tasks one-by-one? Using this scenario, you can have a queue of tasks pending to be executed and you can manipulate them.

Comment: BlockingQueue would just help if tasks are pending. What if I have to remove a command?

Comment: I think that a snippet code, exemplifying what you want. It will help you to get better answers. Write a code that have what you want in the API.

Comment: Added few comments to explain my use case. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Singlethreadexecutor can accept multiple requests.
Once you submit requests , you can get  Future from it. The tasks which have not started can be cancelled and new ones can be submitted.